# Python - Why does this prime factorization function get better performance from this?

Tags: python, primes

I have this prime factorization function that I wrote:

```
def prime_factorization(n):
    prime_factors = {}
    for i in _prime_candidates(n):
        if n % i == 0:
            prime_factors[i] = 0
            while n % i == 0:
                n /= i
                prime_factors[i] += 1
    if n != 1: prime_factors[int(n)] = 1
    return prime_factors

def _prime_candidates(n):
    yield 2
    for i in range(3, int(n**.5)+1, 2):
        yield i
```

It takes around 0.387 seconds on my machine for n = 10^13. But if I copy the content of the for loop and run it for the number 2 before running the actual for loop, I get the same correct results but with a running time of about 0.003 seconds for n = 10^13. You can see that code below:

```
def prime_factorization(n):
    prime_factors = {}
    if n % 2 == 0:
        prime_factors[2] = 0
    while n % 2 == 0:
        n /= 2
        prime_factors[2] += 1
    for i in _prime_candidates(n):
        if n % i == 0:
            prime_factors[i] = 0
            while n % i == 0:
                n /= i
                prime_factors[i] += 1
    if n != 1: prime_factors[int(n)] = 1
    return prime_factors

def _prime_candidates(n):
    yield 2
    for i in range(3, int(n**.5)+1, 2):
        yield i
```

Why does this cause such a massive performance gain?

Edit: I'm using Python 3.5 and I'm using the `clock()` function of the `time` module to benchmark.

Comment: Probably because large numbers have 2 as a very large number of prime factors?

Comment: My guess would be that you're not benchmarking it properly... Did you use [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) for measurement ?

Comment: what version of python are you using?

Comment: Why are you using "this" so much? Makes the question sound very shady and non-specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your initial version, `_prime_candidates` gets passed 10^13, so it generates candidates up to the square root of that.

In your second version, `_prime_candidates` gets passed 5^13, because all the factors of 2 have been divided out. It generates a much smaller number of candidates to test.

By folding the `_prime_candidates` logic into `prime_factorization` and recomputing the upper bound whenever you find a factor, you can get an even better, more general improvement:

```
def prime_factorization(n):
    prime_factors = {}

    factor_multiplicity = 0
    while n % 2 == 0:
        n //= 2
        factor_multiplicity += 1
    if factor_multiplicity:
        prime_factors[2] = factor_multiplicity

    factor_bound = n**.5
    candidate = 3

    while candidate <= factor_bound:
        factor_multiplicity = 0
        while n % i == 0:
            n //= i
            factor_multiplicity += 1
        if factor_multiplicity:
            prime_factors[candidate] = factor_multiplicity
            factor_bound = n**.5
        candidate += 2

    if n != 1:
        prime_factors[n] = 1
    return prime_factors
```

Note that for large enough `n`, the computation of `n**.5` eventually generates the wrong bound due to the limits of floating-point precision. You could fix this by comparing `candidate * candidate <= n`, or by using something like the `decimal` module to compute the bound to sufficient precision.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is inside `_prime_candidates` function.
In your first example it generates all numbers  `3,5,...,3162277` and you try to divide your `n` by all these candidates.

In your second example you firstly greatly reduce your `n` so `_prime_candidates` generates numbers `3,5,...,34939`. it's much less numbers to check.